# cqjni.jar was unexpected at this time- Weblogic server 10.3.3

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to start weblogic server in eclipse but I get error like `\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearQuest\cqjni.jar was unexpected at this time`.I found out that this is causing because of System `PATH` environment variable contains entry of it.I don't have administrative rights (Windows 7) so i can't modify system `PATH` variable.I have defined user defined `PATH` varible but it is getting appended to system `PATH` variable.
So how can I use only user defined `PATH` variable or modify weblogic script to use user defined `PATH` variable?or any other solution?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. But I was able to resolve this issue by doing the below steps.

1. Check for the CLASSPATH variable value in Windows7 using **echo %CLASSPATH%** from command prompt.
2. Check if the CLASSPATH shows the below path
   C:\Program Files\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearQuest\cqjni.jar
3. If Yes, then open the below 2 files in edit mode from the path(Weblogic server)C:\Bea\Middleware\user_projects\domains\XXXX\bin

   3.1 startWebLogic.cmd
   3.2 setDomainEnv.cmd

   and set the **CLASSPATH manually** removing the C:\Program Files\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearQuest\cqjni.jar
4. Start the server, you would be able to start the server then.